# How to redirect MAUI page to Google authentication Login page using .net core

Tags: authentication, .net-core, google-oauth, maui

I have a client application built using MAUI that connects to a different solution, a .net core api that uses .net core identity and authentication using JWT

The code to set up the authentication in this server side web api is as below

```
public static void AddAuth(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(configuration["JWT:Secret"]);

    var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidIssuer = configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
        ValidAudience = configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
        RequireExpirationTime = false,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };

    services.AddSingleton(tokenValidationParameters);

    services.AddAuthentication(options => {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(jwt => {
        jwt.SaveToken = true;
        jwt.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
    })
    .AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
    {
        googleOptions.ClientId = configuration.GetSection("GoogleAuthSettings")
            .GetValue<string>("ClientId");
        googleOptions.ClientSecret = configuration.GetSection("GoogleAuthSettings")
            .GetValue<string>("ClientSecret");

        googleOptions.SignInScheme = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
    });
}
```

As you can see I am trying to integrate google authentication and as far as I understood there's mainly two ways I could try to.

- One would be making the request to the google api directly from the MAUI page, getting a token/code and exchange that on my API to get an authentication token
- Alternatively I could hit my api that in turn talks to the api and then redirects the MAUI app to the google login page. Once authenticated there, google api would call again my api on the callback endpoint which would return the token to the MAUI app

I would really like to have the second option, mainly because I am not maintaining the MAUI app and my knowledge about it is 0. Although as a backup I am trying to understand if by using WebAuthenticator it would be any easy

So after watching quite a few tutorials doing second option I just have this external login endpoint on my account controller

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("external-login")]
public IActionResult ExternalLogin([FromBody] ExternalLogin model)
{
    var redirectUrl = BuildRedirectUrl();
    var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(model.Provider, redirectUrl);
    properties.AllowRefresh = true;
    return new ChallengeResult(model.Provider, properties);
}

private string BuildRedirectUrl()
{
    var returnUrl = "https://localhost:7043/Login";
    var baseUrl = "https://localhost:5001";

    var encodedReturnUrl = UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(returnUrl);

    var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(baseUrl);
    uriBuilder.Path = "/account/external-login-callback/";
    uriBuilder.Query = $"returnUrl={encodedReturnUrl}";

    return uriBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Which seems to do its job to get the login page as per getting the right html. But really struggling to be able to redirect the MAUI page to that google page based on that Challenge. I can't find an example, I just get a whole built html which if I present on the page does fail with a bad request (same as if I present it with postman)

Is there a way to get that redirect working? Is this even a good approach, or is it better to spend my time on making the first (or any other suggested) option?

Thanks

Comment: I think that making the request to the google api directly from the MAUI page will solve the issue.

Comment: Google Auth opens on a WebView doesn't it?